# Terminology: What does it mean to 'instantiate type variables' in Prof. Giesl's Haskell Lectures

Tags: haskell

On page 33 in this document : http://verify.rwth-aachen.de/fp14/FP14.pdf there is the following sentence:

"Dieser Kontext besagt, dass bestimmte Typvariablen nur mit Typen einer bestimmten Klasse instantiiert werden durfen."

So, in English: "This context prescribes that certain Type variables can only be instantiated with those types that belong to certain (in the context defined) type classes."

The corresponding part of Prof. Giesl's Haskell lecture (in English) is at 1 hour and 21 min here : http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=P60Rl-JTgMs .

Could someone please explain what does it mean to "instantiate a type variable" ?

I know what the word instantiate means in the context of OO programming , i.e. to instantiate a class. But what does the word mean in the context of type variables?

As far as I understand the concept of instantiation of type variables pertains only to compile time, more specifically, to the process of type checking. So, instantiation of type variables does not occur at run time. Is this understanding of mine correct?

How should I imagine what happens when a type variable gets instantiated?
When does such a thing happen? How does this fit into the big picture of compiling and running a Haskell program?

Comment: Instantiating just means you have a type variable and the type checker decides its time to give that variable a more concrete value. This will happen when the typechecker needs to unify types. Types only exist at compile time, so (in general) nothing to do with types happens at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A type variable is a placeholder that can stand for different types in a type declaration:  in the declaration `(==), (/=) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, the `a` is a type variable.  To "instantiate" it means to plug in a specific type such as `Int` or `String`, yielding a complete declaration like `Int -> Int -> Bool` or `String -> String -> Bool`.

In this example, the `Eq a =>` means that the type variable `a` can only stand for types that are in the `Eq` class.  You can't use the `==` and `/=` operators to compare values of types that aren't in the `Eq` class.

Type variable instantiation happens at compile time.  You can think of it as the compiler "creating" a version of a function for a specific concrete type (such as `Int -> Int`) from a definition with a generic type (such as `a -> a`).  (This is just a way of thinking about it; the compiler doesn't necessarily actually compile a separate version of the function for each type it's used with.)

Comment: Minor nitpick: If the compiler would create a separate version for each type it would certainly do this when it sees the instance definition. Instantiating is what happens when it sees an expression like `"foo" == a` which causes selection of the String instance.